# C access element in structure

Tags: c, struct

I am finding trouble while I was writing a program in C.
I have defined a structure:

```
typedef struct {
  char* alphabet;         /* Defines the supported characters by the encryption algorithm     */
  char* symbols;          /* Defines the symbols used to encrypt a message                    */
  char* dictionary;       /* Defines the translation for all characters defined in alphabet   */
  char* transposition;    /* Defines the transposition key used in the second encryption step */
} adfgx_machine;
```

I also have created a method to create an instance of this structure:

```
adfgx_machine* am_create(char* alphabet, char* symbols, char* dictionary, char* transposition) {
    adfgx_machine machine;
    if(strlen(alphabet)*2!=strlen(dictionary)){
        printf("s", "Het aantal karakters in de dictionary moet dubbel zoveel zijn als het antal  karakters in alphabet!");
        exit(1);
    }
    machine.alphabet=alphabet;
    machine.symbols=symbols;
    machine.dictionary=dictionary;
    machine.transposition=transposition;
    return &machine;
}
```

Now I am trying to print for example the alphabet of the structure if such a structure is given, but my program always crashes. I have already tried the [dot] operator but that one doesn't work either. Here's my code:

```
void am_create_dictionary(adfgx_machine* am) {
    printf("%s",am->alphabet);

}
```

This is my main method:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv []) {
    adfgx_machine* mach = am_create("azert","azert","azertazert","azert");
    am_create_dictionary(mach);
    return 0;
}
```

So if i replace am->alphabet with am.alphabet it doesn't work either. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

if I don't use my method but print it directly in the main method, it does work?! So then my main method becomes:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv []) {
    adfgx_machine* mach = am_create("azert","azert","azertazert","azert");
    printf("%s",mach->alphabet);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are an enormous number of duplicates of this problem. https://www.google.com/webhp#q=stack+overflow+returning+stack+variable+pointer http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=returning+local+variable+pointer+%5Bc%5D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that you allocate return value on stack. It will be likely to be overriden. You better to use `malloc()`

```
adfgx_machine* am_create(char* alphabet, char* symbols, char* dictionary, char* transposition) {
    adfgx_machine* machine = malloc(sizeof(*machine));
    if(strlen(alphabet)*2!=strlen(dictionary)){
        printf("s", "Het aantal karakters in de dictionary moet dubbel zoveel zijn als het antal  karakters in alphabet!");
        exit(1);
    }
    machine->alphabet=alphabet;
    machine->symbols=symbols;
    machine->dictionary=dictionary;
    machine->transposition=transposition;
    return machine;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are creating the structure variable `adfgx_machine machine;` inside the function `am_create()`, so it becomes the local variable for that function. And, when the function exits, all its local variables are destroyed, along with `machine`.

To accomplish what you want, you can allocate the memory for the variable `machine` dynamically, using `malloc()` or `calloc()`